# [Python][request.get] Wait before geting the page

Tags: python

I want to be able to scrapp data from a website. I use the requests.get fonction to do so. Everything works out fine, except that the said website takes time to full load. Then, when I download it, some parts are not fully loaded.
I tried to use the timeout and stream arguments of the get function but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
acc = open(r'C:\Users\axelg\.spyder-py3\accueil.html','w',encoding="utf-8")

with requests.Session() as s:

    url = 'http://localhost/mysiste.php'
    s.get(url)
    login_data = {'log' : 'myLog', 'pwd' : 'MyPwd'}
    s.post(url, data=login_data)
    r = s.get('http://localhost/location/',stream = True)
    acc.write(r.text)
    
Thank you for your answers !
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the timeout argument the wrong way

```
r = s.get('http://localhost/location/',timeout=(5, 20))
```

The first value of the tuple of timeout argument is to set the session time out and the second value of the tuple is to specify how much time the browser should wait before sending the response. Try changing the second value to suit your requirements

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I did use the timeout fonction exactly this way but it didn't work. Actually the get fonction always take around 0.5 seconds to run, whatever I may have put in the timeout argument.